# HDMI to VGA adapter not working in Ubuntu

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I've read almost everything about connecting a HDMI to a VGA monitor and I couldn't find any solutions.

I have a Hama converter HDMI to VGA ( https://de.hama.com/00054569/hama-hdmi-converter-for-vga?bySearch=00054569 ) connected to an ASUS GL552VW (intel+nvidia 960m).

I've first connected to windows and it worked without a fuss. I've then connected to the same (and only) HDMI port and nothing happens. HDMI port is listed as disconnected. I've tried to connect it to another monitor with HDMI and it works.

There are many posts that rise this problem, some of them remained unanswered and some of them had solutions like - "I swapped the cables and now it works".

I beg you, if you know the answer to this problem, share it, because I don't have money to buy a new monitor and to throw the old one just because it has a vga port.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have already found a solution by now.
I write anyway my experience for the community. :)

I can't tell the exact reason but the fact is that in RECENT notebooks (e.g. asus N552, GL552,...) it's quite difficult to let the hdmi-to-vga converter work. I spent a couple of suffering evenings to find a solution. What I found out is that the cause is INDEED THE ADAPTER.
The most part of amazon/supermarket adapters don't work (although they are suitable for sure for less new models!!).

I found only one working item :
https://www.amazon.it/gp/product/B00R7UKPCE/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o01_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Another solution is using the DP-to-vga converter instead.

I show both the items in the  picture below.

Hope to be helpful. Wait for feedback...

[image]